# Why the output differs in the vectorization?

Tags: r

```
> mean(c(-89,45),99,-765)
[1] -22
> mean(-89,45,99,-765)
[1] -89
> mean(c(-89,45,99,-765))
[1] -177.5
```

Above are few line of codes, this I encountered while learning Vectorization.
I can now understand basic of Vectorization, but somehow I am not able to figure out the output for the below codes.

It would be helpful if someone can explain this to me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you look at `?mean` the `x` argument is a `vector` and the 3rd onein your code is the one that supports

Comment: In other words, it is just the first vector that is used. `mean(c(-89, 45))#
[1] -22` and in the second, you get `-89`, because it is `x`